# Is it possible to implement a function that in C# Winforms that reorganize the elements as Android

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I have this menu (Android style), which is in a `FlowLayoutPanel` that organizes the elements (Bunifu Tile Buttons):

[image]

Well, I thought about implementing a drag function where you could reposition the elements in execution time by dragging them with the mouse as it is done in Android.

To do this, I used a `FlowLayoutPanel` to organize the elements and this code::

```
 ...
 Interval = 100, Enabled = true;      

 private void Timer_0_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      var cursor = Cursor.Position;
      if(bunifuTileButton1.DisplayRectangle.Contains(cursor))
      {
         if(Hector.Framework.Utils.Peripherals.Mouse.MouseButtonIsDown(Hector.MouseButton.Left))
         {
              bunifuTileButton1.Location = cursor;
         }
     }
}
```

But when I drag the elements, they simply return to their original position by releasing the mouse button.

So, my question is:

> Is it possible to implement a function that in C # Winforms that reorganize the elements as Android does using a `FlowLayoutPanel` that automatically organizes the elements in execution time?

Comment: What [`ControlStyles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) do you have set? Really you should be setting the [`Form.Opacity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity(v=vs.110).aspx) to something, not drawing a rectangle.

Comment: Only fake Transparency in Winforms. Or set Opacity < 1 to make the __whole__ form semi-transparent. There are 100 thousand references to this.

Comment: If i recall, OnPaintBackground only change the buffer when first called and when it resized. OnPaint does it on gazillion of events such as move, control added....

Comment: Works just fine on my system, did you set some other properties in the control styles?

Comment: What other form settings are you using? I copied your code and it doesn't create any type of opacity, so I must be missing something to reproduce what you are seeing.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, the code you posted, when copied into a new Winform, doesn't create any transparency. If I set `Opacity` to some value (like 0.5f), the opacity works fine.

Comment: You are not really supposed to change a question to something totally different; not such a big issue here since you didn't get an answer but you see that now we shall delete the comments. You ought to ask a new question and (probably) delete this one..

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartinezDurán As TaW said, don't change a question, delete it and start again. While your question may not have been answered, something may have been useful to somebody else in the future. New questions are free, no need to completely change an old one for something entirely new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly , you need to implement the functionality which will help you drag-and-drop your controls.But before that, you need to store the control's current position in some class-level variables.Consider the following code snippet :

```
 int xloc;
 int yloc;

 ///other codes in-between

 private void btn1_Click()
 {
    xloc = this.btn1.Location.X;
    yloc = this.btn1.Location.Y;
 }
```

Now the drag-and-drop feature :

```
private Point setNewLocation;

private void btn1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        setNewLocation= e.Location;
    }
}

private void btn1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        btn1.Left = e.X + btn1.Left - setNewLocation.X;
        btn1.Top = e.Y + btn1.Top - setNewLocation.Y;
    }
}
```

This will help you move the control...But what happens when you place a control over another one ? I mean you definitely don't want one control to overlap the other.Rather you may want to,when one control is placed over the other, the other control will change it's position to the previous position of the control that is overlapping it.So, on the `MouseUP` event of the currently dragged control , use this :

```
private void btn1_MouseUP()
{
   foreach (Control other in FlowlayoutPanel1.Controls)
   {
     ///change control type as required
    if (!other.Equals(btn1) && other is Button && btn1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(other.Bounds))
    {
        other.Location = new Point(xloc, yloc)
    }

}
```

I haven't debugged the code so if you encounter any bug, make sure to leave a comment :)